# C++ inheritance function override

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to C++ and I am coming from Java/C#.

I know that in Java and C# you can make a class, have another class inherit from it, and override its function. You can then make list of the parent class and insert to this list objects of the child class. After that you can use it's functions that were overridden.

Example:

```
public class Parent
{
  public virtual void test()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("test");
  }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
  public override void test()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("test2");
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Parent> tests = new List<Parent>();
tests.Add(new Child());
tests[0].test();
```

Output:

> ```
> test2
> ```

In C++, ***when I do this with `std::vector`***, it calls the parent's member function, rather than that of the child.

How can I do the above in C++?

Comment: use the construct in c++ that is nearest to java references: pointers.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: No, do not use pointers except when forced to, and if you do, only use smart pointers.

Comment: @sbi: The OP is clearly in the need of a collection to polymorphic elements of different dynamic type, thus a pointer is the most appropriate thing to use. Whether to use a smart pointer or not is entirely outside of the scope of this question, since to properly judge that we would need to determine what kind of smart pointers to use, and all this is probably more confusing than helping, given the basic level of understanding of the language presented in the question.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: But _is_ UnTraDe really in need of OO-style polymorphism? Maybe templatizing his algorithm to work with different types (plus any container type!) would do, too?

Comment: @sbi: yeah, indeed, did he ask the right question. Did he maybe not even need C++ at all? Shall we continue wondering what he wants, or shall we try answering his question on how to do these things in C++?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I am in favor of the latter. These things are best done using Generic Programming in C++, rather than OO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I feel like there's two problems here for you. One is a syntactical problem, which others have already addressed. However, it seems that you also have an underlying problem of ***trying to write Java/C# code in C++***. This will lead to misery no matter what the syntactical problems are, so I try to address this here.

> In c++ when I do this with vector it calls that parent's function. How can I do the example above in C++?

***Java and C# use the object-oriented paradigm for everything***. C++ is different in that ***C++ is a multi-paradigm language***. It supports (more or less) Structured, OO, Generic, Functional and whatnot Programming paradigms. You can freely ***mix and mingle paradigms***, and C++ shines brightest where you do that.

The part of the standard library that derives from the STL, that is: containers, algorithms, iterators, are not OO at all. They are applying ***Generic Programming***. One of the attributes of that is that the containers usually (there are exceptions, but not within the standard library itself) store *values*, rather than *references*. Polymorphism, however, at least *runtime* polymorphism, only operates on *references* (or, syntactically, pointers, which are, semantically, references, too).

If you have a `std::vector<base_class> vc`, this will store actual *values*, rather than references to objects somewhere on the heap. If you put an object into such a container, the object will actually be *copied* into the container. If you put in a `derived_class` object, then that is subjected to ***slicing***. That is, only the `base_class` part of it will be copied into the container, all the `derived_class` parts will be disregarded. You then end up with an actual `base_class` object in the container, rather than, as in Java and C#, a base class reference to a derived class object somewhere on the heap.
That is why invoking a member function on that object will end up in the base class: ***there is no derived class object to invoke a function on***.

In C++, ***if you want to employ OOP***, you will usually have to ***dynamically allocate derived class objects*** (i.e., `new derived_class()`) and assign them to base class pointers. The problem with this is that C++ does not have garbage collection, so you must keep track of those pointers, and all the copies made from it, and explicitly delete the object just before the last pointer gets destroyed. That is ***very error-prone to do manually***, which is why nowadays everybody lets ***smart pointers*** do this automatically.

So what you want is `std::vector<smart_ptr<base_class>>` and put in `new derived_class()` objects. What the symbolic `smart_ptr` refers to depends on your needs. If you plan to store pointers to those objects *nowhere but in that container*, `std::unique_ptr` (`std::tr1::unique_ptr` if your compiler only supports C++03, or `boost::unique_ptr` if it doesn't even support that) would be ideal. If you freely pass around such pointers, and them to keep track of when the last goes out of scope for themselves, `std::shared_ptr` would be better.

---

Now, all this said, I feel the need to add: ***You might not need to do this the OO way at all***. There might be a much better design if you could just let go of the rigid OO thinking Java and C# have imprisoned you in.

If you employ polymorphism just so you can pass containers with different content to the same algorithms, then employing ***Generic Programming might be much better***:

```
template<typename FwdIt>
void do_something(FwdIt begin, FwdIt end)
{
  while(begin != end)
    if(begin->foo() == bar()) // whatever
      begin->baz();           // whatever
}

std::vector<some_class> vs;
std::vector<other_class> vo;
std::deque<other_class> do;

// ...

do_something(vs.begin(), vs.end());
do_something(vo.begin(), vo.end());
do_something(do.begin(), do.end());
```

This works for all types (here it's `some_class`) that have a `foo()` member not taking any arguments and returning something comparable with whatever `bar()` returns, and have a `baz()` member, not taking any arguments either. (If you try to use some type that doesn't have those, the compiler will bark at you.)

Comment: Good answer, but note that you can do OOP style polymorphism in C++ using references as well as pointers. According to the standard, an l-value of a derived class can be bound to a reference to an accessible unambiguous base class. Just one less place you need to use new/delete :-)

Comment: @bstamour: That's why I qualified this statement with "usually". `:)`

Comment: Wow thanks alot! But I didn't understood 2 things: 1. The last part of your answer with the generic programming 2. Why it is so bad to use oop?

Comment: @UnTraDe: OOP isn't bad per se, it's just bad to mindlessly apply it to everything. ("If all you have is OO, everything looks like a thumb.") The last part of my answer employs templates to solve the problem using _Generic Programming_. Very superficially, templates are like Java's and .NET's generics — only very different. `:)` What I do is to pass _iterators_, rather than containers. I then turn the function into a function templates, to allow it to work with any kind of iterators. You might need to [read up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/140719) on templates.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Java or C#, C++ uses value semantics by default.  An
`std::vector<Parent>` contains actual objects of `Parent` type, and not
pointers or references.  When you insert into the vector, the object you
are inserting is copied, and it is copied into an object of `Parent`
type.  (Objects can't change type.)  This is called slicing.

If you want to use polymorphism in C++, it is necessary that you specify
explicitly that you want reference semantics.  Both pointers and
references provide reference semantics, and it's possible to define
"smart pointers"—classes which behave like a pointer to some other
class.  Since references don't support the copy/assignment semantics
required by the standard containers, they can't be used to instantiate a
container, so if the container is to hold polymorphic objects, it must
be defined to contain pointers.  So:

```
std::vector<ValueType> v;
v.push_back( ValueType() );         //  no new
```

but

```
std::vector<BaseType*> v;
v.push_back( new DerivedType() );   //  dynamic allocation.
```

Because of slicing, polymorphism and copy/assignment don't work well
together, and it is usual to block copy/assignment in classes designed
to be the base of a hierarchy.

Also, if you are going to manage objects through pointers to the base
class, the destructor should be virtual:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Parent() {}
    //  ...
};
```

Otherwise, you'll run into undefined behavior when you go to delete the
object (through a pointer to its base).

Comment: You're a bit terse where you explain slicing, but at least this, too, addresses the OP's actual problem. `+1` from me for that.

Answer (score 1):

`test()` should be made `virtual` in your `Parent` class to make sure that the `Child` class's `test()` is being invoked.

Comment: The actual question is a bit buried in the text, but 45mins should be enough to thoroughly read the whole thing and find it, even when it's only in the next-to-last sentence. Your answer doesn't even address this question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `boost::ptr_container` library would be very helpful for you.
It works in the same manner as a vector of (smart) pointers but it has the added benefit of having syntax designed for use as such.

So for example you can do the following:

```
typedef boost::ptr_vector<AbstractClass> PolyVector;

PolyVector polyVect;
polyVect.push_back( std::unique_ptr( new ChildClassA() ) );
polyVect.push_back( std::unique_ptr( new ChildClassB() ) );
polyVect.push_back( std::unique_ptr( new ChildClassC() ) );

BOOST_FOREACH( PolyVector::value_type item, polyVect)
    item.memberFunction( x );
```

Which will call the derived class implementation of the virtual `memberFunction`.

Comment: Yep, _boost::ptr_container_ is good for this, too. `+1` from me.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't have an `override` keyword. Just redeclare your overridden method as `virtual`.

Comment: But then when I call test() the output is test instead of test2 (it seems like this is calling the parent's function)

Comment: @Nawaz It's not a "keyword", it's a special identifier.  And it's placed at the end of the function declaration.  (In any other context, it's just another symbol.)

Comment: The actual question is a bit buried in the text, but 45mins should be enough to thoroughly read the whole thing and find it, even when it's only in the next-to-last sentence. Your answer doesn't even address it.

Comment: @sbi: I've answered in the first 5 mins the question was issued. There wasn't even that sentence you're talking about (std:vector ...). I didn't take a further look after the edits to the original question. Sorry if my answer doesn't address the (now edited) question anymore ...

Comment: @g-makulik: That sentence has always been there. I only changed formatting to make it more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, this would look something like the following:

```
MyList<Parent*>* tests = new MyList<Parent*>();
tests->Add(new Child());
tests->test();
```

In order to invoke polymorphic functionality in C++ where you would call the child's function and not the parents, you have to use either pointers or references that point or reference the parent class, and the class methods themselves need to be declared as `virtual` in the parent and child class declarations.

Keep in mind that using raw pointers like this could cause some serious memory leaks if you do not compensate for the fact that the `MyList` object "owns" (or should own) the pointers being passed to it.  If ownership is ambiguous, you need to be extra careful, or use something like `std::shared_ptr<T>`.  For instance, if you decided to use a STL container like `std::vector` with raw-pointers, then the container will not "own" the memory allocated to each pointer, and when the container is destroyed, it will not free the memory being pointed to by each of it's members, resulting in a nasty memory leak.

BTW, this is a very important point about C++ ... unlike C#/Java, C++ uses explicit, not implicit pointers.  Therefore if you declare an object such that it is not a pointer (i.e., it's a static, or "automatic" variable on the stack), then if you copy a derived class instance object into a parent instance, you will end up "slicing" the parent portion of the derived object off, and just copying the parent portion of the derived object.  That's not what you want.  You want polymorphic behavior, and therefore you must use pointers or references to the parent class-type.

For instance, here is a [working example](http://ideone.com/vb0Pj) of polymorphic behavior:

```
#include <iostream>

//polymorphic base
struct test
{
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "I'm the parent" << std::endl; }
};

//derived type
struct derived : public test
{
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "I'm the derived" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    test* a = new test;
    test* b = new derived;

    a->print();
    b->print();  //calls derived::print through polymorphic behavior

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use std::vector but I dont understand why it's have to be with pointers or references.

Comment: Because you want polymorphic functionality ... you can't get that without using a polymorphic class, and then calling a pointer on that class so that you go through the class' v-table and call the correct parent/child function

Comment: This does nothing to explain how to do this using `std::vector`.

Comment: @sbi The OP has edited the original answer to include the use of `std::vector` ... if that is why I was down-voted, then please take into account the requested use of `std::vector` was only a comment from the OP on my answer at the time I originally answered the question.  Since the request for `std::vector` wasn't part of the original question, I didn't include it.

Comment: @Jason: No, _I_ have edited to original _question_, making the reference to `std::vector` more apparent. It's always been in there, though.

Comment: Thanks it helped me to understand!